# Una consulta SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo una duda algo rebuscada quiero saber si hay alguna forma de resolverla:

Tengo una tabla llamada `PRODUCTOS` con estos atributos:

```
ID, NOMBRE, FECHA
```

Tengo una tabla llamada `ESTADO_PRODUCTOS` con estos atributos:

```
ID, PRODUCTO_ID, ESTADO_ID, FECHA
```

Tengo una tabla llamada `ESTADOS` con estos atributos:

```
ID, NOMBRE_ESTADO
```

Ahora bien como ya vieron se trata de:

`ESTADOS_PRODUCTOS` tendrá muchos estados de `PRODUCTOS` y `ESTADOS` estará muchas veces en `ESTADOS_PRODUCTOS`.
Eso quiere decir que `ESTADOS_PRODUCTOS` tiene una relación muchos a muchos entre *estados* y *productos*, ya que un *PRODUCTO* pasara por diferente transiciones de estados.

Perfecto hasta allí, resulta que tengo este caso supongamos:

`ESTADOS_PRODUCTOS`

```
ID, PRODUCTO_ID, ESTADO_ID, FECHA
1     1             1       00:00:00
2     2             1       00:00:00
3     3             1       00:00:00
4     1             5       00:00:00
```

Yo estoy haciendo una consulta en este momento entre `PRODUCTOS` y `ESTADO_PRODUCTOS`. En un principio hice una consulta donde le dije que me mostrara todos los `PRODUCTOS` que tiene en `ESTADO_PRODUCTOS` el `ESTADO_ID = 1`

Pero, si se dan cuenta, por ejemplo, el `PRODUCTO_ID = 1` está dos veces en la tabla `ESTADO_PRODUCTO` con el `ESTADO_ID` `1` y `5`

Pregunta:

¿Es posible hacer una consulta donde me muestre todos los `PRODUCTOS` con `ESTADO_PRODUCTOS` iguales a `1`, pero donde los `PRODUCTOS_ID` que ya tiene otro estado sean excluidos?

Es decir, para este ejemplo, quiero saber si podríamos ver los `PRODUCTOS` `2` y `3`, porque el `1` ya tiene otro estado.

Yo tengo este query hecho pero, vamos, que no me sirve para lo que quiero:

```
   SELECT 
   *
   FROM
   productos
   inner join estados_productos on productos.id = estados_productos.producto_id
   WHERE
   estados_productos.estado_id not IN (
   SELECT 
        estados_productos.estado_id
    FROM
        estados_productos
    WHERE           
   estados_productos.estado_id = 5
        
   )
```

Obviamente se darán cuenta que la consulta me retorna todos los productos con ESTADO_ID = 1, pero yo ya no quiero ver el PRODUCTO 1, porque ya no me interesa.
Yo quisiera excluir a todos esos `PRODUCTOS` que tienen 1 y 5.

Espero puedan darme una idea de como se hace. Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La solución en SQL se escribe casi de la misma forma que lo has dicho en lenguaje natural. Tu has dicho:

> una consulta donde me muestre todos los PRODUCTOS con `ESTADO_PRODUCTOS` iguales a `1` pero donde los `PRODUCTOS_ID` que ya tiene otro estado sean excluidos

Vamos por partes, la consulta para obtener todos los productos con estado 1, sería como esta:

```
SELECT productos.*
  FROM productos
       inner join estados_productos on productos.id = estados_productos.producto_id
 WHERE estados_productos.estado_id = 1
```

De este resultado, ahora, debemos excluir a todos aquellos que tengan cualquier otro estado, para ello, podemos valernos de una condición `not in`, por ejemplo, teniendo una consulta que nos devuelva el `id` de todos los productos que tienen otro estado. Veamos ahora qué consulta nos daría esa información, por ejemplo:

```
select producto_id
  from estados_productos
 where estado_id != 1
```

Ahora, solo necesitamos juntar todas las piezas:

```
SELECT productos.*
  FROM productos
       inner join estados_productos on productos.id = estados_productos.producto_id
 WHERE estados_productos.estado_id = 1
   and productos.id not in (select producto_id
                              from estados_productos
                             where estado_id != 1
                           )
```

**OJO**, que has dado dos descripciones de lo que buscas que no son exactamente iguales. Por un lado, en el texto citado, has dicho que quieres mostrar todos los productos que tengan estado 1, excluyendo los que tengan cualquier otro estado.

Luego, más adelante, has dicho que quieres excluir los que tengan estado `5`. Mi respuesta cubre el primer caso, si la entiendes estoy seguro que no te será difícil adaptarla para el segundo.

Comment: Muchas Gracias por tu respuesta...sabia que me faltaba algo y ese algo ya me lo has explicado. Muchas gracias.